# Gravity form show form dynamically

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

my question I'm sure is a simple one but one that I am completely stumped on.
I have 4 gravity forms say, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4.
I want the user to select from a dropdown which area they want. There are 4 areas. So if they choose Area 1 in the drop down,I want gravity form ID1 to load dynamically below the drop down.
If they choose area 2, then gravity form with ID2 loads etc. You get the picture.
Is there a very simple solution to this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your forms are - I would simply make one form with the 4 forms in it that display VIA conditional logic. The first thing (and only thing) you see is a drop down to choose options ID1 to ID4 and then based on that selection the conditional logic allows the parts of that form to be displayed.